# Why isn't my component rerendering on state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why isn't mu `render` method called when state is changed? I want to show the next image on next button click and the previous image on previous button click, but my `render` method is not called when I update state. Here's [a live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/g5wl3vBRl).

I updated state like this:

```
 next(){
    var current = this.state.currentSlide;
    var next = current + 1;
    if (next > this.props.stories.items.length - 1) {
      next = 0;
    }
    this.state.currentSlide = next;
    console.log(this.state.currentSlide ,"next---")

  }
  pre(){
    var current = this.state.currentSlide;
    var prev = current - 1;
    if (prev < 0) {
      prev = this.props.stories.items.length - 1;
    }
    this.state.currentSlide = prev; 
      console.log(this.state.currentSlide ,"pre---")
  }
```

Here's my `render` method:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="imageSlider">
          <ul>
            {this.renderStories()}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.next}>next image</button>
        <button
          onClick={this.pre}>pre image</button>

      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never, ever, mutate properties of the `state` object outside of the constructor. Mutation of an object such as state leads to a whole bunch of issues and is the source of all evil. Use [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to set the state:

```
this.setState({
  currentSlide: next
});
```

Per [Using State Correctly at the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly):

> #### Do Not Modify State Directly
>
> For example, this will not re-render a component:
>
> ```
> // Wrong
> this.state.comment = 'Hello';
> ```
>
> Instead, use `setState()`:
>
> ```
> // Correct
> this.setState({comment: 'Hello'});
> ```
>
> The only place where you can assign `this.state` is the constructor.